# Ionic3 , Firebase | Line skipping

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a function for add data to Database(Firebase)

Like below

```
addLibrary(indexOfLibrary){
        
    this.cityInfo = this.indexOfLibrary.nameOfCity;
    this.libraryInfo = this.indexOfLibrary.nameOfLibrary;

    this.database.list('Libraries/').valueChanges().subscribe((data) => {

      for (let cityInfos of data) {
        console.log(cityInfos.nameOfCity +" -----" + this.cityInfo);
        if(cityInfos.nameOfCity==this.cityInfo){
          this.anyOtherLibrary=true;
        }else{}
      }
    });
    console.log("Is there another Library?= " + this.anyOtherLibrary);
.
.
.
```

When I start project lines not compiling line by line I guess

This picture why I am telling this: [image: Click Me]

This is the console of Google Chrome but logs did not came line by line order

**As you see I need to see firstly this line**

`console.log(cityInfos.nameOfCity +" -----" + this.cityInfo);`

***and when*** `this.database.list('Libraries/').valueChanges().subscribe((data) =>`

***operation is over I need to see***

```
console.log("Is there another Library?= " + this.anyOtherLibrary);
```

Is there any idea why this is happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. This means that the `console.log` happens before the data has been loaded. There is no way to wait for the value. Instead, any code that requires the data must be (called from) inside the `subscribe` callback. If you put your `console.log` in there, it'll execute after the data has loaded, and will print the right result.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me about how it works.